# Applications of Jordan-Holder theorem in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

The Jordan-Holder theorem says that any chain of subobjects of a finite lenght object can be refined to a composition series, and that any composition series has the same lenght.

This theorem holds for any abelian category, and a notable example is the case of modules over some ring. While I do not need an example of the usefulness of J-H theorem in the context of modules, I would like to ask:

> What are applications of the J-H theorem in a general abelian category,
>   which is not (or not easily proven to be) a category of modules?

Comment: The Jordan-Hölder property means that the simple objects form a basis for the Grothendieck Group of the category, which gives something akin to a “character” of an object similar to characters of representations of finite groups.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you give me a reference (or elaborate a little) ? thx

Comment: I found a reference. This is for eg. in "Tensor categories" page 5 or in Weibel's K-book

Comment: Do applications for quasi-coherent modules on schemes also count?